# Selecting multiple id's and hovering using jquery each() and hover()

Tags: jquery, html, dom, loops, jquery-plugins

Please kindly take a look at this code. I'm selecting all the element with the same ids, however, only the first element changes color, when you hover on the other elements, their color remain the same. Not sure if I'm doing it the right way.. Please kindly offer suggestions.

A life demo is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/bwoodlt/2ReCe/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ade").live("hover", function(){
            $("#ade").each(function (){
            $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
           // alert("In here..")
        });

        });
    });
```

Update:

Thanks Guys! I did use the class selector, it selects all the elements on-hover! What I really want is for it to select each element on hover, then as I proceed to the next element, that should change the color rather than selecting all the element and changing their color when one item is hovered!

Comment: ID's **must** be unique.

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: "all the element with the same ids" => that's the problem..

Comment: your code could be simply:   `$(".ade").on("hover", function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
           // alert("In here..")
        });` no need for each inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, IDs must be unique. Also, your code doesn't make sense anyway. When you hover over any div, you loop through every other div, and apply the highlighted class to each div. Surely you only want to add the highlighted class to the hovered div? In that case, drop the .each(). And don't use .live(), it's deprecated. Use .hover() if you need to, or if you need delegated events, use .on().

```
$(".ade").hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ReCe/2/

Comment: exactly my comment at same time :) with slightly differing syntax.

Comment: Thanks Christian! Excellent! :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss except the hover event doesn't work with .on(), you need to use mouseenter and mouseleave! http://jsfiddle.net/2ReCe/3/

Comment: @ChristianVarga Yes, the pseudo event is removed in 1.9, so you should use the enter/leave as you indicated - it is in the 1.9 release notes.

Answer (score 2):

It's [illegal in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) to have more than one element with a given ID. `$('#ade')`  uses `getElementById` and returns only one element.

Use a class for this case. `$('.ade')` will return all elements having class `ade`.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use an ID on one element. jQuery will only select the first element with the ID given. Use a class for multiple.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are meant to be unique, only one element with a certain ID should exist on a page, and jQuery will select only one element when using an ID selector. If you want to group multiple elements together and select them, I suggest you create a class and use that selector.

```
$('.test')
```